# Copying a registry key

Tags: powershell, registry

I am trying to make a simple PowerShell script that copies some registry folders and substrings in these folders to it's own folder on the C:\ drive.

How can I do this?  I've tried export command, and `Copy-Item -Path` command but without luck.

For example copy the files (registry files) in the keys

```
HKLM\software\Norton
HKLM\software\Wow6432Node\Norton
```

to the folder `C:\backupNorton`.

Comment: Hi, can you please clarify : do you expect `.reg` files in that folder at the end of the process ? What have you tried already ? Please post some code so we can help debug. To clarify : registry keys are not folders.

Comment: I guess you may like this : https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742017(v=ws.11).aspx I don't think there is a PS equivalent, I bet this native command is still widely used nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
Get-ChildItem HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Norton
```

And then export or save the object you get from that - either as plain text or using something like `Export-Clixml`.